# Routes in ruby with rails, html forms not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby with rails,I generated a new Controller named users by using command:

```
rails generate controller users register index login
```

After that I opened `register.html.erb` and wrote following code:

```
<h1>Register New User</h1>
<p>
    <%= form_for :user do |f| %>
    <%= f.label:USERID %><%= f.text_field:userid %><br />
    <%= f.label:PASSWORD %><%= f.text_field:password %><br />
    <%= f.label:EMAIL %><%= f.text_field:email %><br />
    <br />
    <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
</p>
```

Then in `users_controller.rb` I wrote following code in register:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def show
  end

  def login
  end

  def register
      print "test"
  end
```

def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:userid,:password,:email)
  end
    end

And test is not being printed and get and post methods of the form are not working at all.
And `params.require(:user).permit(:userid,:password,:email)` is not working as well. I get error that `:user` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

> I get error that :user is empty.

`form_for(path/to/your/controller/action)` is a helper method to create HTML form elements with the url path to the POST or GET request. The helper knows if it should be a new record or an update record based on what you are asking to do in your controller action. So, basically, it's looking for the `@user` in the corresponding controller action when you write `form_for @user` in your view. As you don't have it currently, hence you ar getting this error.

See [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object) for more information.

To solve your current problem, you have to define the `@user` in the controller's `register` action:

```
  def register
     @user = User.new(user_params)
  end
```

Then, in your `register.html.erb` file's form, you can use that `@user`:

```
<h1>Register New User</h1>
<p>
  <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :USERID %>
      <%= f.text_field :userid %><br />
      <%= f.label :PASSWORD %>
      <%= f.text_field :password %><br />
      <%= f.label :EMAIL %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %><br />
      <br />
      <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

Comment: still getting this error: param is missing or the value is empty: user

Comment: Use `@user` NOT `:user` in your view's form. Look at my code carefully please.